# Android Push Notification > migrate from Legacy FCM API to HTTP V1 API > payload

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cordova, push-notification

my app receives remote push notifications with title, text, sound and image.
All works fine with the Legacy FCM API but with the new HTTP v1 API i run into an issues.

I use a modified version of this plugin in my corova app:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

**The image wont displayed, title, text and sound working:**

Payload:

```
{
   "message":{
      "token":"***********",
      "data":{
         "title":"Title",
         "body":"Message",
         "sound":"s9",
         "picture":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/demo\/image\/upload\/w_200\/lady.jpg",
         "style":"picture",
         "image":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/demo\/image\/upload\/w_200\/lady.jpg",
         "color":"[255, 255, 255, 0]",
         "channel_id":"s9",
         "mid":"39511026"
      },
      "notification":{
         "title":"Title",
         "body":"Message",
         "image":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/demo\/image\/upload\/w_200\/lady.jpg"
      },
      "android":{
         "priority":"HIGH",
         "restricted_package_name":"******************",
         "notification":{
            "title":"Title",
            "body":"Message",
            "default_vibrate_timings":false,
            "vibrate_timings":[
               "0.1s",
               "0.5s",
               "0.1s",
               "0.5s",
               "0.1s",
               "0.5s"
            ],
            "color":"#ffff00",
            "default_light_settings":true,
            "light_settings":{
               "color":{
                  "red":255,
                  "green":255,
                  "blue":0,
                  "alpha":1
               },
               "light_on_duration":"1.0s",
               "light_off_duration":"1.0s"
            },
            "icon":"ic_notify",
            "notification_priority":"PRIORITY_MAX",
            "sound":"s9",
            "channel_id":"s9",
            "image":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/demo\/image\/upload\/w_200\/lady.jpg"
         },
         "data":{
            "title":"Title",
            "body":"Message",
            "sound":"s9",
            "vibration":"3",
            "url":"",
            "picture":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/demo\/image\/upload\/w_200\/lady.jpg",
            "style":"picture",
            "image":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/demo\/image\/upload\/w_200\/lady.jpg",
            "color":"[255, 255, 255, 0]",
            "channel_id":"s9",
            "mid":"39511026"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**The image is shown, but no sound, when i only send the data block**

```
{
   "message":{
      "token":"***********",
      "data":{
         "title":"Title",
         "body":"Message",
         "sound":"s9",
         "picture":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/demo\/image\/upload\/w_200\/lady.jpg",
         "style":"picture",
         "image":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/demo\/image\/upload\/w_200\/lady.jpg",
         "color":"[255, 255, 255, 0]",
         "channel_id":"s9",
         "mid":"39511026"
      }
   }
}
```

code you will find here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3hwsjkixrpm46tpaj9m7i/FCMService.java?rlkey=xn8grhcghrc1jefyg33c5a088&dl=0

What do i wrong? How to fix the issue?

Thanks Kevin